# Validate empty cells Angular Xlsx file

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, typescript, xlsx

Good morning I have a problem, I am loading an xlxs file, I read the file without problems, but if the loaded file has an empty cell I should show an error message indicating that there are one or more empty cells.

***Function to read my file***

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
onFileChange (evt: any) {
    const data: [] [];
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer> (evt.target);
    if (target.files.length! == 1) throw new Error ('Cannot use multiple files');
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader ();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read (bstr, {type: 'binary'});
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames [0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets [wsname];

      this.data = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json (ws, {header: 1, defval: null}));
      console.log ("data:", this.data);
      // I apply slice to skip the headers.
      let x = this.data.slice (3);
     console.log ("x:", x);
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString (target.files [0]);

  }
```

***Image of the data extracted from the archive***
[Image of the data extracted from the archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEM3b.png)

***Format of my exce file
l***
[Format of my exce file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktUp6.png)

Here comes my question, how could I perform a validation that allows me to save all null values ​​in a list or something similar, and then show the error message to the user or if you have any other solution to solve my problem, thank you very much.